# How to take the values of object by passing string

Tags: javascript

I have an object array with values and need to get the items by passing a string as the node
below is the code which i tried,

```
var c = "Rice";
// based on the value "c" i should get the item from selectedItems array
    console.log(selectedItems.c);
    // It should call selectedItems.Rice
    // selectedItems=[{
    "Rice":{[1]}
    }]
```

expected output: {[1]}

Comment: The question is unclear. Could you elaborate? As I understood... If you have an array of objects, please give an example of those. Where do you want to pass a string? To some kind of function? What should be the result?

Comment: updated the question could u please check? @NikitaSkrebets

Comment: `{[1]}` isn''t valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const result = selectedItems.filter(item => item[c]);
```

This way you will iterate through the entire array, and get the first object occurrence that contains a property named as the "c" variable value.